# How to read xlsx file uploaded in django?

Tags: python, django, openpyxl

I have a django server which allow user to upload xlsx files, I want to access the data in it.

I know about openpyxl, however, it looks like it doesn't have a way to parse opened files, I do not want to save the file on disk and read it again.

How can I do it?

Comment: You'll have to write your own code to pass the zip archive into openpyxl. Much better to save it somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

Actually, it's simpler than above:

```
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            wb = load_workbook(filename=request.FILES['file'].file)
```

The `file` attribute of `FILES['file']` already returns a BytesIO instance ;)

Answer (score 6):

Read it as bytestream.
[This explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20667890/7840653) helped me for the same task
My solution:

```
    from openpyxl import load_workbook
    from io import BytesIO
    ...
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = UploadForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file_in_memory = request.FILES['file'].read()
            wb = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(file_in_memory))
```