# Open Excel file from zipfolder in openpyxl

Tags: python, openpyxl

I am trying following code.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
from openpyxl import load_workbook
from io import BytesIO

zip_path = r"path/to/zipfile.zip"
with ZipFile(zip_path) as myzip:
    with myzip.open(myzip.namelist()[0]) as myfile:
        wb = load_workbook(filename=BytesIO(myfile.read()))
        data_sheet = wb.worksheets[1]
        for row in data_sheet.iter_rows(min_row=3, min_col=3):
            print(row[0].value)
```

it shows

> ValueError: stat: path too long for Windows

Is this possible?

I am trying logic from [Using openpyxl to read file from memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20635778/using-openpyxl-to-read-file-from-memory)

Comment: Your code uses xlrd and not openpyxl.

Comment: I mixed things up. Let me retry.

Comment: I have corrected the mistake. Is it still possible?

Comment: Have you tried this code?  `xlrd` would give the error you show because it would try to use the `BytesIO` you passed as a filename (use `file_contents` instead with xlrd), but cursory look at the code seems to indicate that openpyxl will detect the difference.

Comment: file_contents works. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With xlrd following code works fine.

```
with ZipFile(zip_path) as myzip:
        with myzip.open(myzip.namelist()[0]) as myfile:
            book = xlrd.open_workbook(file_contents=(myfile.read()))
    sh = book.sheet_by_index(0)
    #your code here
```